# how can I implement n native ad on exit box dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, native-ads

I am wondering is it possible to show a native ad on the app exit box dialog.
Like when user click back to close the application then on the dialog box user will see a native ad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible . You can achieve this by using custom layout for dialog and showing ads in the custom layout